# How to implement Auth0 on Nestjs and using by Flutter (JWT)

Tags: authentication, jwt, nestjs, auth0

I'm currently develop authentication and authorization on project that use:

- Backend: Nestjs
- Database: MongoDB with @nestjs/mongodb library for schema declare
- App: Flutter
- Strategy: JWT - passport

I want to transfer to Auth0 for better secure but the docs kinda drive me crazy.

I tried to following to this [tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-a-secure-api-with-nestjs-adding-authorization/#Which-Comes-First--The-Authorization-Chicken-or-the-Authentication-Egg) and [this](https://auth0.com/blog/flutter-authentication-authorization-with-auth0-part-4-roles-permissions/) but I'm still not sure.

1. Should I sign up from Flutter SDK or though Nestjs? And how to do in Nestjs?
2. I already set mongodb on auth0 with its script (set, get, verify,...). When create new user does the user information go to db or will duplicate on Auth0 and db?
3. On create user, i have to set all the user info in metadata. Can i modified it to suit current user schema ?

EDIT: I just notice when login with FlutterSDK, token will return to app, can i use it for nestjs jwt validation?